# C++ DLL not executing function after injection

Tags: c++, vb.net, dynamic, dll, code-injection

Okay so I made a DLL injector in VB.net a while ago. It works fine with any DLL except for mine. So I know the problem is with the DLL. Here is the injector's code:

```
Private Function Inject(ByVal pID As Integer, ByVal dllLocation As String) As Boolean
    Dim hProcess As Integer = OpenProcess(&H1F0FFF, 1, pID)
    If hProcess = 0 Then
        Return False
        MessageBox.Show("Could not open process!")
    End If
    Dim dllBytes As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dllLocation)
    Dim allocAddress As Integer = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, 0, dllBytes.Length, &H1000, &H4)
    If allocAddress = Nothing Then
        Return False
        MessageBox.Show("Could not allocate the address!")
    End If
    Dim kernelMod As Integer = GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll")
    Dim loadLibAddr = GetProcAddress(kernelMod, "LoadLibraryA")
    If (kernelMod = 0) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Could not get the Module")
        Return False
    End If
    If (loadLibAddr = 0) Then
        MessageBox.Show("get the Process address!")
        Return False
    End If
    WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, allocAddress, dllBytes, dllBytes.Length, 0)
    Dim libThread As Integer = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, 0, 0, loadLibAddr, allocAddress, 0, 0)

    If libThread = 0 Then
        Return False
        MessageBox.Show("Error Creating thread!")
    Else
        WaitForSingleObject(libThread, 5000)
        CloseHandle(libThread)
    End If
    CloseHandle(hProcess)
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    Return True
End Function
```

This writes the process memory and creates a remote thread.

Now my project has two files: the header and the CPP File.

Header:

```
#ifdef MAINLIB_EXPORTS
#define MAINLIB_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MAINLIB_API __declspec(dllexport)
#endif

extern "C" MAINLIB_API DWORD TestFunction();
```

And the CPP:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "dll.h"
#include "Urlmon.h"

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HANDLE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
        hModule;
        lpReserved;

    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
        {
                case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
                case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
                case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
                case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
                        break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

DWORD TestFunction()
{     
        MessageBox(0, TEXT("LOL"), TEXT("LMAO"), MB_OK);
        return 1;
}
```

From what I understand is that this should run TestFunction on injection. But it doesn't. Any solutions/helpful pages I could use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing in your code that specifies `TestFunction` needs to be called. Once the DLL is attached to the process only DllMain and global objects needing initialization are called. You need to call `TestFunction` when processing `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH`.

```
DWORD TestFunction();

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HANDLE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    hModule;
    lpReserved;

    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        TestFunction(); // < call TestFunction ONCE when dll is loaded
        break;

    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

DWORD TestFunction()
{     
        MessageBox(0, TEXT("LOL"), TEXT("LMAO"), MB_OK);
        return 1;
}
```